# php convert integer primary key (id) to string

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

i want to convert `id` to `string` in my sql query result.

i want to response json with string id ...

i tried `convert(id, char)` and `cast(id as char)` in `select` but problem remains ...

example:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Success",
  "nexturl": "http://domain.dev/feed/298",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 123456789,
      "userid": 12,
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to get this result:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Success",
  "nexturl": "http://domain.dev/feed/298",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "123456789",
      "userid": "12",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821528/int-to-string-in-mysql)?

Comment: you need to post (full) relevant code as well as db schema.

Comment: Dont build your own JSON Strings. Use `json_encode($an array or an object);` to do it. Then it will be correct. Yours probably wont be most of the time. ___A few minutes now and again with the manual can save you hours of pain___ [And here is the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @DominiqueLorre
yes like that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [int to string in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821528/int-to-string-in-mysql)

Comment: @Fred-ii-
i have an table with auto increment `id` ... and i'm using query builder in cakephp 3 for get result...

Comment: @RiggsFolly
i didn't build json manually...i'm using json_encode ...

Comment: Why do you need the `id` as a string and not a number may I ask?

Comment: i want to use json in android, ios and windows mobile ...  integer may have 32 or 64 bits ... i want to prevent overflow in some platforms ...
@RiggsFolly

Comment: @mostafaznv You should double check you actually need 64 bits because 99% of the time you don't. If you're Twitter, Facebook or Google, *sure*, it makes sense, but 2.1 billion identifiers take a long time to exhaust for more ordinary applications. Hint: [`strval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php).

Comment: @tadman yes i know ... but my boss insists to response string ids :D

Comment: Then `strval` it is. You didn't post the code where you render the JSON, but as RiggsFolly says, use `json_encode`. Where you have an integer value now, convert it when passing it through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650306/cakephp-3-x-how-to-change-the-data-type-of-a-selected-alias/35652166 See **Change the type of existing columns**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i found the answer**

we can convert columns in entity class...

so i created an entity for `users` table and i converted the primary key (`id`) in entity.

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
       '*' => true,
    ];

    protected function _getId($id){
        return (string) $this->_properties['id'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`CONVERT(id, CHAR(50)) as id` is the correct syntax.

Comment: This is better done within PHP. It's utterly pointless to do it in the query since there's an additional layer involved anyway.